# Is it possible to access custom control coded in ANDROID project through Xamarin Forms project?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, native

I want implement a custom listview control with some additional features which is coded in android project (native code) ,

and render that custom control in my forms project .

is it possible to do so?

[ I have already read many articles does the reverse (control coded in forms and accessed in android project) ]

Comment: Maybe you add some more details on what you plan to do. Usually you create a control in shared code, and then add a platform-specific custom renderer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You can use a [Custom Renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) to expose a native control (custom or otherwise) in Forms.